# How do I find what to refer to a UIButton as?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uibutton

I want a particular `UIButton` to change colour once a `UISwitch` move from `OFF` to `ON`. What do I enter

```
- (IBAction) Court1ON {
//here
}
```

to refer to a specific `UIButton` in my storyboard?

Comment: What ever `IBOutlet` instance variable you connected to the control in the nib file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several possibilities to do that:

1. assign a `tag` to your button in storyboard; then access the button through:

   ```
   [self.view.viewByTag:buttonTag];
   ```
2. create an `IBOutlet` `@property` of type `UIButton` and bind that to your button.

Comment: thanks a lot, sorted it out now.